# Class has no memeber UID - Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display the data in one of my firebase database files and everytime I do that even though when the codes right. I seem to be getting a bad instruction syntax or "Class has no member uid" error. Any ideas what I should be doing?

```
      databaseRef.child("followers").child(self.user!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

I can't seem to find out where I went wrong!

Comment: try this: Auth.auth().currentUser.uid

Comment: try reading this [Manage Users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

Comment: Looks like you are saving `currentUser` to class variable (are you?), can you show some more code so we can see how are you doing it?